# Image causing other objects to move

Tags: css

After inserting an image into my template, a set of boxes further down the page seem to have drifted out of sync with the rest of the template and I'm baffled as to why. I have tried messing with certain padding and margins and can't seem to keep the image along with the correct alignment.

**The Code**

```html
<div id="SuperContentsWrapper">
  <div id="SuperContents">
    <div id="SuperContentsSub">
      <h1>
        <div align="center">
          <font color="#A35E41"><em><font color="#000000">Batman Vs Superman Boys' T-Shirt</font></em></strong></font>
        </div>
      </h1>
    <p>
    <div align="center"> <img src="http://nutty-squirrel.co.uk/Kieran%20Completed%20SKU%20/Batman%20Test.png?" height="100%" width="100%">
      <p>
      <div align="center">
        <font size="3">Great for all occasions, this Batman Boys T-Shirt will receive a great reception anywhere. This T-Shirt looks and feels great and is made with 100% innovative SofSpun Cotton and has a longer-line for a more fashionable looking T-Shirt.</font>
      </div> 
      <p> </p>
      <div align="center">Brand: Fruit Of The Loom </div>
```

The image causing the issue is: `<div align="center"> <img src="http://nutty-squirrel.co.uk/Kieran%20Completed%20SKU%20/Batman%20Test.png?" height="100%" width="100%">`

Please let me know if there is anymore code needed to understand why this is happening!

Comment: Please post a working jsFiddle link

Comment: First, provide a [mcve] in your question please.

Comment: There is no closing `</div>` tag after the image - this will break the rest of the document flow.

Comment: @KallumTanton this seems to have resolved the issue. 1 hour of fiddling and you just type 6 characters for me. Phenomenal. Thank you!

Comment: @Kf071289 No problem, sometimes a second pair of eyes is the best medicine. Andy Holmes and j08691 it's often worth ensuring that the provided code is fully correct before requesting extra information which may not be necessary. I've expanded my comment into an answer for completion - please mark it as correct if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

To expand my answer in the comments, the lack of a closing `</div>` tag after the image meant that the browser engine would render everything following that unclosed `<div>` as being inside that `<div>` until a matching closing tag was found, which will cause damage to the entire visual layout thereon downwards.